# Adding request.authenticated_userid to SQLAlchemy objects in Pyramid

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm using "versioned history table" SQLAlchemy mixin described here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html#module-examples.versioned_history

It works nicely, adds "changed" column to the history table that records timestamp of the change but I also need to record *who* changed the record (audit trail).

In Pyramid that is normally available in `request.authenticated_userid` if you use typical authentication and authorization subsystems available in Pyramid.

Great. But how to make history mapper (part of a mixin) make use of that value?

That is, apart from `changed` column I would like to have `changed_by` (`request.authenticated_userid`) column in the `_history` table. Preferably without adding it manually to the history table record.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the solution:

`history_meta.py` contains `create_version` function that is registered for `before_flush` SQLAlchemy event (by `versioned_session` defined in a mixin).

In `create_version` one has to get the current transaction:

```
current = transaction.get()
```

The user is available in `current.user`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not SQLAlchemy expert however I do use Pylons Pyramid with SLQAlchemy and that's how I access userid from my event (below is just to show the idea):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    scoped_session,
    sessionmaker,
    )

from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension
from pyramid.threadlocal import get_current_request

DBSession = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()),
    scopefunc=get_current_request)

Base = declarative_base()

# Define your tables

@event.listens_for(Base, "after_insert", propagate=True)
def user_after_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    try:
        user_id = DBSession.registry.scopefunc().userid
    except AttributeError:
        # most likely initializedb script is being called
```